# HTML form and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to be able to enter a url in a form so that when I press "submit" it redirects to a different url, but retaining the parameters from the original url.

Simply,

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=somequery

redirects to

https://www.google.com/search?q=somequery

I am assuming this can be done with a simple form and Javascript.

Anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Please research your needs on Google or some other search engine and try something. Then if it doesn't work you can post here with your existing coffee and what part of it isn't working.

Comment: @Loren Did you mean “existing code” instead of “existing coffee”?

Answer (score 1):

Since text-based formats like URLs are usually full of special cases, I prefer to leverage the parser already embedded in the browser:

```js
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var parser = document.createElement('a');
  parser.href = document.getElementById('url').value;
  window.location = 'https://google.com/search' + parser.search;
});
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
URL: <input id="url" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

(it looks like google does not like being embedded in an iframe)

Comment: Why make an `<a>` element for parsing the URL? Just use `new URL(document.getElementById("url").value).search;`.

Comment: @Xufox while I don't know whether my solution works in IE, yours definitely doesn't, which is definitely something to keep in mind.

Comment: I have been trying this and some other code examples but cannot get this to work. For me it does not work here or in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Grove/4eeptak2/6/ I would have expected a new tab to open but nothing happens.

Comment: @Packwood to open a new tab you should use `window.open` instead of `window.location`, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4eeptak2/11/). It doesn't seem to work because Google doesn't like being embedded in an iframe, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have sorted it. It seems to be some problem between google.com and gogle.co.uk that was not redirecting as I expected. On another pair of websites it works as expected.